# How to match words containing characters and digits, but not numbers?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create in Python a regular expression that matches words that contains `A-Za-z` or `A-Za-z0-9`, but not only `0-9`.

For example I want to match `fooT`, `foo23`, `fo24ooo`, `fo4o444`, but NOT `40`.

Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible. What have you tried? What have you come up with, and in what way did it not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be:

```
r'\w*[A-Za-z]\w*'
```

`\w` matches `_` as well as 'A-Za-z0-9' - if that's wrong, write out the whole class:

```
r'[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*'
```

Comment: `\w` will also possibly match additional characters if the LOCALE or UNICODE flags are set, which may not be desired behaviour.

Comment: True, but `UNICODE` and `LOCALE` are not in effect unless actively specified when creating the regexp.

Comment: I would add: `^[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$` but otherwise spot on.

Comment: I used just the whole class and it works fine! The "how it works" still confuses me. Thank you very much Peter.

Comment: For how it works - well, `*` matches any number of characters from the class, including 0. So in English, that would be "any number of letters or digits, even zero. Then exactly one letter. Then any number of letters or digits, even zero". It requires at least one non-digit character, but that non-digit can be anywhere in the string - 'f00', '0f0', and '00f' all work.

Comment: Yes, reading carefully your comment i finally understood it! Clever way of thinking! Thanks again.